Streaming a Async function in Flask
I have this python code:
@app.route('/chatstm', methods=['POST'])
async def chatstm():
    if 'user_id' not in session:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Unauthorized'}), 401
    
    # Obtenha os parâmetros da requisição
    message = request.json.get('message')
    pdf_pc_id = request.json.get('pdf_pc_id')
    pdf_id = request.json.get('pdf_id')
    conversation_id = request.json.get('conversation_id')
    
    # Construir o objeto de chat
    chat = build_chatstm({
        "pdf_pc_id": pdf_pc_id,
        "conversation_id": conversation_id,
        "pdf_id": pdf_id
    })
    
    async def generate():
        # Iterar sobre os eventos assíncronos do chat
        async for event in chat.astream_events(
            {"input": message},
            config={"configurable": {"conversation_id": conversation_id}}, 
            version="v2"
        ):
            if event["event"] == "on_chat_model_stream":
                yield f"{repr(event['data']['chunk'].content)}"
        
                

    return Response(stream_with_context(generate()), content_type='text/event-stream')


and it always returns me this error:
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jun/2024 22:17:58] "OPTIONS /chatstm HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Debugging middleware caught exception in streamed response at a point where response headers were already sent.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ericluque/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 256, in __next__
    return self._next()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ericluque/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers/response.py", line 32, in _iter_encoded
    for item in iterable:
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

I need to stream this data, but the only function available with the characteristics I need is a async one. I've looked in the entire internet, tried iterate the iterator, and so on.. Nothing works
Can someone help me to fix it ?

Don't make us guess where the error happens.  Please edit the question and add the full error traceback message.

And this is a minor point, but why f"{repr(event['data']['chunk'].content)}"?  repr() already returns a string, so why not just repr(event['data']['chunk'].content)?

It was just a matter of use. I was concatenating with other var and.left as is

I'm not in the pc right now, but the issue is that the async is not used by stream_with_context. I'll paste de whole error as soon as I back to my pc

Use an asyncio.Queue to collect events from your asynchronous generator.
Have a separate coroutine that pulls from the queue and yields items.
Stream from this coroutine using Flask’s stream_with_context.

queue = asyncio.Queue()
async def generate():
async for event in chat.astream_events(
{"input": message},
config={"configurable": {"conversation_id": conversation_id}},
version="v2"
):
if event["event"] == "on_chat_model_stream":
await queue.put(repr(event['data']['chunk'].content))
await queue.put(None)
async def stream_response():
while True:
chunk = await queue.get()
if chunk is None:
break
yield chunk
asyncio.create_task(generate())

Still have the same problem

Provide more details on the build_chatstm function and the chat.astream_events method.

Ilya, just found the error and solution.. shared below

I found the solution based on the comment from @MahendranR. stream_with_context does not work with async functions and it was not receiving the iterator obj. The only method I could capture the LLM events with was astream_events, which is a async method.
I was implementing a chain in lagnchain using RunnableWithMessageHistory which has a default implementation of stream mocking invoke method and I had to implemented by myself, so I created I new StreamingHandler to my LLM in this way:
class StreamingHandler(BaseCallbackHandler):
        def on_llm_new_token(self, token, **kwargs):
            queue.put(token)

        def on_llm_end(self, response, **kwargs):
            queue.put(None)

        def on_llm_error(self, error, **kwargs):
            queue.put(None)

and created this class StreamingChain(RunnableWithMessageHistory) overriding the stream using Thread:
class StreamingChain(RunnableWithMessageHistory):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        def stream(self, input, config):
            def task(app_context):
                app_context.push()
                self.invoke(input, config)

            Thread(target=task, args=[current_app.app_context()]).start()
            
            while True:
                token = queue.get()
                if token is None:
                    break
                yield token

